# How to set a text based on the enum values in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, enums

I have a group of enum values which are defined for various actions based on the user input. Now I need to pass a string based on enum value. How do I do that?

```
enum status: {
    signed_up: 0,
    docs_uploaded: 1,
    approved: 2,
    rejected: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="accountstatus">  
  <p> <%= @current_user.status %> </p> 
</div>
```

Instead of calling `<%= @current_user.status %>` in a div, I want to assign string value to those enums as such:

0 : Successfully Registered 
1 : Documents Uploaded 
2 : Account approved 
3 : Account rejected

Comment: Simply change the 0, 1, 2, 3 numbers to meaningful strings. Will work just as well.

Comment: @GillesLesire Can I keep the values as it is and append only the strings using jQuery as it is being referenced in other parts of the site also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
en.yml
    user:
      status: 
        signed_up: Successfully Registered
        docs_uploaded: Documents Uploaded 
        approved: Account approved 
        rejected: Account rejected

.html.erb file
    <div class="accountstatus">  
      <p> <%= t("user.status.#{@current_user.status}") %> </p> 
    </div>
```

Use translation file to show your string. You can later localize your strings for different languages.

========================================

## Second Approch

```
helper file : add method

def get_status_name(code)
  statuses = {"0" => "Successfully Registered", "1" => "Documents Uploaded", "2" => "Account approved", "3" => "Account rejected"}
  return statuses["#{code}"]
end

<div class="accountstatus">  
  <p> <%= get_status_name(@ current_user.status) %> </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can I keep the values as it is and append only the strings using jQuery as it is being referenced in other parts of the site also?

Comment: I added another approch please check.

Comment: I am getting the following error @Sachin R -> syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END statuses = {:0 => "SAwaiting Documents", :1... ^ /home/avid/web/app/helpers/users_helper.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end ...= {:0 => "SAwaiting Documents",.... for all the values

Comment: What to do for this error? -> uninitialized constant UsersController::GetStatusName

Comment: get_status_name is helper method